# バブルソートで操作をした後に毎回printする方法

Tags: python

Pythonについての質問です。バブルソートを実行するために、以下のようにプログラムを組んだのですが、操作した後に毎回printしたいです。そのようにするためにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

例えば `[3,5,1,7]` と与えられたら以下のように抽出したいです。

```
[3,5,1,7]
[3,1,5,7]
[1,3,5,7]
```

**現状のコード:**

```
def BubbleSort(num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        for j in range(len(num)-1, i, -1):
            if num[j] < num[j-1]:
                num[j], num[j-1] = num[j-1], num[j]
return num
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def BubbleSort(num):
    print(num)
    for i in range(len(num)):
        for j in range(len(num)-1, i, -1):
            if num[j] < num[j-1]:
                num[j], num[j-1] = num[j-1], num[j]
                print(num)
    return num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BubbleSort([3,5,1,7])

# [3, 5, 1, 7]
# [3, 1, 5, 7]
# [1, 3, 5, 7]
```