# バブルソートで確認した後に、毎回printするようにプログラミングする方法について

Tags: python

再度失礼いたします。
バブルソートで、１ステップ毎に配列の内容をprintで表示させながら並び替えるようにする方法について教えていただきたいです。
私が間違えて書いたプログラムは一番下に掲載します。

例えば、([3,6,1,4])が与えられたら

```
[3, 6, 1, 4]
[3, 6, 1, 4]
[3, 1, 6, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```

と出力したいです。　ご教示お願いいたします。

```
def print_bubble_sort(s):
    print(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s)+1, i, +1):
            if s[j] < s[j+1]:
                s[j], s[j+1] = s[j+1], s[j]
                print(s)
    return s
```

Comment: 前の同様の質問(https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93491/) に回答が付いていますが、その回答では駄目なのでしょうか？

Comment: 前回質問の各`-1`を`+1`に変えているのは何故でしょうか？ それから表示する回数を増やしたいのはどの箇所でしょう？ 例えば「１ステップ毎...表示」という「１ステップ」とは何処から何処までを指すのかを明確にしてみてください。なお要素が4つくらいなら手作業で取り得る値の範囲と途中経過を全て書き出せるでしょうから、それで確認してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 前回の回答では、printするのは数字を入れ替えたときだったのですが、今回は数字を入れ替えていなく、ただ数字が小さい順になっているか確認している操作もprintしたいのです。また、-1から＋1に換えた理由といたしましては、前回のプログラムで、適当な数字を与えたのですが、うまく並べ替えが起こらなかったからです

Comment: それは前回の質問記事に、上手くいかなかった時の入力データとその上手くいかなかった結果を追記して、質問を継続するのが良いやりかたでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

希望の出力例は「未ソート部分の最大要素を部分の最後に移動し全体として末尾から順に確定していく」方法の出力と思われるので，その記述例と出力を示します。

```
def print_bubble_sort(s):
    print('i j', s)
    print('-' * 20)
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        for j in range(len(s) - 1 - i):
            if s[j] > s[j+1]:
                s[j], s[j+1] = s[j+1], s[j]
            print(i, j, s)

print_bubble_sort([3, 6, 1, 4])
```

```
i j [3, 6, 1, 4]
--------------------
0 0 [3, 6, 1, 4]
0 1 [3, 1, 6, 4]
0 2 [3, 1, 4, 6]
1 0 [1, 3, 4, 6]
1 1 [1, 3, 4, 6]
2 0 [1, 3, 4, 6]
```